# How to select the array in which the element exist

Tags: php, arrays

I want to select the array in which the element exist

```
Array ( 

  [0] => Array ( [0] => woman [synonym] => lady [1] => girl [word] => girl )

  [1] => Array ( [0] => man [synonym] => man [1] => boy [word] => boy )

)
```

If I use

```
array_search('girl', $array);
```

It will just return the key, but I want to select the `num` of the array and later on, to get that data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
function filter($array) {
    return in_array('girl', $innerArray);
}
$filter = array_filter($yourArray, 'filter');
```

The same concept using PHP-5.4 callbacks in a single line:

```
array_filter($array, function($innerArray) {return in_array('girl', $innerArray)});
```

Comment: Thanks :), but this is in a foreach loop so the **keyword** is changing.